# Is React still managing event delegation as of v15.4.0?

Tags: reactjs, event-delegation

In a commit authored on Oct 21st 2016, the snippet about React handling event delegation has been removed from the docs. Is React no longer doing this as of v15.4.0?

This was the commit that had major documentation changes, including this one: https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/455d2d1b48e5cdaeac5d0b4fd92b29b4d52bcaec

The snippet I'm referring to was this one:

> **Event delegation**: React doesn't actually attach event handlers to the nodes themselves. When React starts up, it starts listening for all events at the top level using a single event listener. When a component is mounted or unmounted, the event handlers are simply added or removed from an internal mapping. When an event occurs, React knows how to dispatch it using this mapping. When there are no event handlers left in the mapping, React's event handlers are simple no-ops.